# Convert Int to Time like 123430 to 12:34:30

Tags: c#

I would like to Convert Int to Time like 123430 to 12:34:30 in c#. Below code didnt work

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(timeint.ToString(), "HH:mm:ss",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Tip: the format string is the format of the input, not the output. See how far that gets you.

Comment: That can't be an int if it is divided into HH:MM:SS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format string is the format that the inputted string is in. For example in your case `HHmmss`, just remove the colons and you should be fine.

Like:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(timeint.ToString(), "HHmmss",
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```